# store a HTML element in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, appendchild

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to append</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("LI");
  let textNode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  let water = newLi.appendChild(textNode);
  console.log(water);    // water variable doesn't store the node object that represents the appended node
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(water);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a question regarding return value of appendChild() method. The definition says the return value of appendChild() is "node object that represents the appended node". It is not a string data type. So, I just tried to store the return value in a variable (water variable in the code above). But, the variable just stores a string data type. Is that because variable cannot store a HTML element as its value?

Comment: `console.log('water')` will always log the string value "water", not the value of the variable called "water".

Comment: Also, you don't really want to append that text node to the list anyway, you want to append your newly-created `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to log the actual variable, not the literal string `'water'`. After that:

The `water` variable *does* append the created text node - if you do `console.log(water)` and see just `"Water"`, this is just the console trying to be "helpful" and display the contents of the node to you, instead of displaying a JavaScript object. But the value really does contain the object.

You can also use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` to get the console to display the object itself, instead of the HTML markup of the node.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("LI");
  let textNode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  let water = newLi.appendChild(textNode);
  // console.log(water);
  console.log(typeof water);
  console.log(water instanceof Node);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1jym.png">

<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to append</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

> Is that because variable cannot store a HTML element as its value?

There is absolutely no problem with storing an HTML element in a variable.

You can use the return value of `appendChild` more to make your code more concise if you wanted, with the `<li>`. You don't need to create a text node and save it in a variable, you can just assign to the `.textContent`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const newLi = document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(document.createElement("LI"));
  newLi.textContent = 'water';
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to append</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: _"if you do `console.log(water)` and see just `"Water"`"_ - OP logs the string `'water'` and not the variable `water`

Comment: In Chrome, the only hint appears to be the slight indentation before the `"Water"` that gets logged. It doesn't look very intuitive.

Comment: Why doesn't console.log() just print out the return value, which is node object? I understand what you said: console is just trying to be helpful. But, it's a bit weird to me because I thought console.log() always returns a correct returned value. I usually use Chrome console, and the result I'm getting is the string value as you have explained...Some console does print out the text node instead of string. P.S. I've already edited the mistake, which is console.log('water'); to console.log(water). Thank you.

Comment: @Kinta The behavior of `console.log` differs between browsers. In Chrome, it will generally print the `.outerHTML` (or equivalent) of the element being logged. 95% of the time, this is a good thing: it's a lot more informative to see, for example, `<span class="someClass">some content</span>` than to see `{ HTMLSpanElement accessKey: '', ariaAtomic: null, ariaAUtoComplete: null` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The appendChild does return the node appended. When you used createTextNode('water') you'll notice it also returns the text only. Thats cos a textNode is just text.

If you used appendChild with an html element instead of just the textNode, then it will return the complete element.

In your case `newLi` holds

```
<li>Water</li>
```

If you had

```
let newLi = document.createElement("LI");
let newSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
let textNode = document.createTextNode("Water");
let water = newSpan.appendChild(textNode);
let waterItem = newLi.appendChild(newSpan);
```

Here `waterItem` is `<span>Water</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code **water** references the text node but not the added **LI** element. So the result is "water". Also, you should add the **newLi** but not **water** into **myList**.

In the code below the return value of appendChild and newLi will be the same.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let textNode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  newLi.appendChild(textNode);  
 var added= document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(newLi);
  console.log(newLi);
  console.log(added);
}
</script>
```

Output:

```
<li>Water</li>
<li>Water</li>
```